# BindingResolutionException when using constructor params in Laravel 5 Command

Tags: php, laravel, command, laravel-5

I am making a command that is invoked via controller. When I do a simple example command and controller like this, it works:

```
//Controller
$command = new TestCommand();
$this->dispatch($command);

//Command
public $name;

public function __construct()
{
        $this->name = 'hi';
}

public function handle(TestCommand $command)
{
        dd($command->name);
}
```

When I invoke the command via the controller, I get 'hi' which is correct. But when I try to pass something through the constructor, I get the binding resolution exception:

```
//Controller
$command = new TestCommand('hi');
$this->dispatch($command);

//Command
public $name;

public function __construct($name)
{
        $this->name = $name;
}

public function handle(TestCommand $command)
{
        dd($command->name);
}
```

Why is this? What I did looks identical to what I found in the Laravel docs example, yet I get this exception:

BindingResolutionException in Container.php line 872: Unresolvable dependency resolving [Parameter #0 [  $name ]] in class App\Commands\TestCommand

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is because of dependency injection. If you used in your constructor object like `User $user` or `Guard $auth` Laravel would inject those objects to constructor so you had this properties set. But Laravel cannot inject simple type variables so you get this error.

You can also read on [docs](http://laravel.com/docs/5.0/bus#creating-commands) page:

> Of course, the constructor allows you to pass any relevant objects to
>   the command, while the handle method executes the command.

so it won't work for non-object paramters